# Could not receive FCM background notification via following an official Microsoft sample

Tags: firebase, xamarin, xamarin.android, firebase-cloud-messaging

I am following this tutorial for receiving FCM background notification  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/android/data-cloud/google-messaging/remote-notifications-with-fcm?tabs=macos .

I used "Test on device" from Firebase to send messages: 
[image]

But I get the following error

`[FirebaseMessaging] Unable to log event: analytics library is missing
[FirebaseMessaging] Missing Default Notification Channel metadata in AndroidManifest. Default value will be used.
[FirebaseMessaging] Error while setting the notification channel
[FirebaseMessaging] java.lang.NoSuchFieldError: No static field fcm_fallback_notification_channel_label of type I in class Lcom/google/android/gms/R$string; or its superclasses (declaration of 'com.google.android.gms.R$string' appears in /data/app/com.xamarin.fcmexample-sq_amXpUDW9K_irSBnrndA==/base.apk)
[FirebaseMessaging]     at com.google.firebase.messaging.zza.zzrj(Unknown Source:195)
[FirebaseMessaging]     at com.google.firebase.messaging.zza.zzs(Unknown Source:273)
[FirebaseMessaging]     at com.google.firebase.messaging.FirebaseMessagingService.handleIntent(Unknown Source:189)
[FirebaseMessaging]     at com.google.firebase.iid.zzg.run(Unknown Source:26)
[FirebaseMessaging]     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1167)
[FirebaseMessaging]     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:641)
[FirebaseMessaging]     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:764)`

Does anyone know how to fix it? Or does anyone know a workable tutorial for getting Xamarin Android app to receive FCM background notification?

BTW: It seems to me that the tutorial is sort of outdated, as the Firebase console UI is quite different from what has been introduced in the sample. Microsoft should update the tutorial, it is quite frustrating that I found out that a tutorial is outdated and it did not work when I followed everything that I can.

Answer (score 0):

I have a feeling that the receiver is missing kindly check if you have added the following to your manifest file:

```
  <receiver android:name="com.google.firebase.iid.FirebaseInstanceIdInternalReceiver" android:exported="false" />
    <receiver android:name="com.google.firebase.iid.FirebaseInstanceIdReceiver" android:exported="true" android:permission="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.SEND">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE" />
            <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.REGISTRATION" />
            <category android:name="${applicationId}" />
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
```

Kindly check if this works and if not revert also make sure the receiver is inside the `<application>` tag and not the `<manifest>` tag.

**Update:**

Also, check if a notification channel is needed in your MainActivity. You can call this method in the onCreate method :

```
void CreateNotificationChannel()
    {
        if (Build.VERSION.SdkInt < BuildVersionCodes.O)
        {
            // Notification channels are new in API 26 (and not a part of the
            // support library). There is no need to create a notification 
            // channel on older versions of Android.
            return;
        }

        var channel = new NotificationChannel(CHANNEL_ID, "FCM Notifications", NotificationImportance.Default)
                      {
                          Description = "Firebase Cloud Messages appear in this channel"
                      };

        var notificationManager = (NotificationManager) GetSystemService(NotificationService);
        notificationManager.CreateNotificationChannel(channel);
    }
```

Where

```
    internal static readonly string CHANNEL_ID = "my_notification_channel";
    internal static readonly int NOTIFICATION_ID = 100;
```

are the definition for channel id and notification id respectively.